# ListView edit cell placement wrong

Tags: list-view

After applying in-line style to a .ms-listviewtable it renders nicely however clicking "edit this list" and then clicking into a cell to edit it causes the edit cell to jump to the right, outside of the table.

Your edit works but the interface is not acceptable.

Appreciate any response.

Comment: What do you want to render? Maybe there is an other option

Comment: As I stated above I added some styling to a .ms-listviewtable specifically the default all items view. I found a snip in another post and used it and as I said it rendered nicely just didn't work when you wanted to edit a list item.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the offending style is:

```
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

Boarders had been applied and the above assisted the correct rendering of the right column.

For now I have removed that portion of the styling and edit works as expected.
In order to render the right boarder on the last column I set a boarder to the list rather than the table row.